# Hibernate relationship - one class include relation to multiple entities of the same type

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship

I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class Parcel implements Serializable
{
    @OneToOne
    private Place sender;
    @OneToOne
    private Place recipient;
    @Column
    private String number;
}
```

As you can see, I have two objects of Place there. How I can create a relation between Parcel objects and Place objects? Is it possible to have two `@OneToOne` mapping between this objects or I should use `@Embedded` to do this. 
I need to have a sender data and receiver data of the parcel, but they are of the same type. What is best way to solve that problem?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know how this relationship should look in Place entity. Also, I do not know if it is a good way to solve this problem.